# 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextFactory`1[TContext]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TContext'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

It's my first time using asp 5\core1 and i'm having problem setting a entity framework dbcontext

I have one class library with my object

```
public class Utilizador
    {
        public Utilizador()
        {

        }

        public int id { get; set; }
    }
```

Then i have a Web Api project with a reference to my class and a context

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Utilizador> Utilizadores { get; set; }

}
```

My package.json its like this regarding entity framework

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools":  "1.0.0-preview1-final" ,
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
    "imports": [
      "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
      "portable-net45+win8"
    ]
  }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
```

And finally my startup.cs

```
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
      services.AddEntityFramework().AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]));

    }
```

I used the command Add-Migrations and it created my database and one table called __MigrationsHistory but didnt created any for my class so i used the Add-Migration "mycontext" and everything stopped working, now everytime i try to do a migration i get this error:

```
System.ArgumentException: GenericArguments[0], 'WebApiSolution.Migrations.Context', on 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextFactory`1[TContext]' violates the constraint of type 'TContext'. ---> System.TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[0], 'WebApiSolution.Migrations.Context', on 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextFactory`1[TContext]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TContext'.    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(RuntimeTypeHandle handle, IntPtr* pInst, Int32 numGenericArgs, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(Type[] inst)
   at System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.RuntimeType.ValidateGenericArguments(MemberInfo definition, RuntimeType[] genericArguments, Exception e)
    at System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.DbContextOperations.FindContextFactory(Type contextType) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.DbContextOperations.FindContextTypes() 
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.DbContextOperations.FindContextType(String name)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.MigrationsOperations.RemoveMigration(String contextType, Boolean force)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.MigrationsRemoveCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0()
    at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args) 
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
 GenericArguments[0], 'WebApiSolution.Migrations.Context', on 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextFactory`1[TContext]' violates the constraint of type 'TContext'.
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction? what am i doing wrong, what am i missing here?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a database initializer to your context:

Edit: My initial answer was based on Entity Framework 6. Database.EnsureCreated() sounds like it might be the equivalent method in the latest release:

```
    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options)
        : base(options)
    {
         Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
```

Comment: didnt worked cant even find those methods for database, i know there were some pretty big changes in the last version and its hard to find ppl using it yet... :/

Comment: the problem was actually in the package dependencies and tools, i redid it and added some more l, restarted vs and now it works... maybe a bad reference or something was the problem... if needed will post the changes later... thanks

Comment: @Shakawkaw Can you post exactly what fixed your issue? I'm having the same one. Following a tutorial to learn so I'm not sure exactly what is wrong with my project.json tools and dependencies.